# GCC module dependencies

Tags: c, gcc, module, include, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to compile app which using cross module dependencies?
When I try to compile modules using standard function & other module functions

```
gcc module.c -c
gcc module2.c -c
gcc module.o module2.o -o app
```

I get errors like

```
implicit declaration of function printf
```

I know it can be handled by including all headers in each file and using #define & #ifndef but it's very ugly. I'd like to include all files in app file like this:
app.c

```
#include "macro.h"
#include "module.h"
#include "module2.h"

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {}
```

(module.h & module2.h omitted)

macro.h

```
#define macro(var1, var2) var1 ? printf(var2) : moduleFunc(var2)
#define macro2(var) some math func
```

module.c

```
void moduleFunc(char* var) {macro2(); module2Func();}
```

module2.c

```
void module2Func(...) {macro(); printf(...); some math func}
```

Comment: Why is it ugly to tell a compiler the things that the compiler needs to perform its task? It is like having an employee and say to that employee you cannot know about this tool but have a good guess what it could be!

Comment: Having in each file some lines like
#ifndef STDIO_H
#define STDIO_H
#include <stdio.h>
#endif
is ugly.

Comment: And that is ugly? A couple lines of characters in a file? This could be considered ugly - but his girlfriend thinks otherwise. http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http://www.thearchnemesis.com/images/angler%2520fish.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.thearchnemesis.com/Ugly%2520Fish.html&h=266&w=400&sz=55&tbnid=B3YhsMI2JPfBBM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=135&zoom=1&usg=__wELGU655O-l-_EgIFikAC5fTmIM=&docid=zE9IqtSDyVCYNM&sa=X&ei=yZBAUeCkGsO50QWe7oCwAg&ved=0CDgQ9QEwAA&dur=217

Comment: BTW Source code is not suppose to be beautiful. If you want that go to the local art gallery.

Comment: @Lukasik If you're having to implement your own header guards in your files, then the compiler you are using is broken. You should be able to just `#include <stdio.h>` and be done with it. The header guards should be in the include files, not your source files.

Answer (score 0):

Include `stdio.h` in your `macro.h`. That way any module, that is trying to `macro.h` header will use `printf` declaration from `stdio.h`